# Display Product Availability on Parent Product Page for Both Simple and Variable Products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have this code in functions.php to display product availability for Simple and Variable products of a particular Category. We use our site both for class registration and physical product sales, so CategoryID 138 is the parent Classes category.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'custom_get_availability', 1, 2);

function custom_get_availability( $availability, $_product ) {
  global $product;
  $stock = $product->get_stock_quantity();
  $catIDs = $product->get_category_ids();

  if (in_array("138", $catIDs) and $_product->get_manage_stock()) {
    if ( $_product->is_in_stock() ) $availability['availability'] = __($stock . ' spots left in class', 'woocommerce');
    if ( !$_product->is_in_stock() ) $availability['availability'] = __('CLASS FULL', 'woocommerce');
  }
  return $availability;
}
```

This works great for Simple products and the individual variations of Variable products. Not so well for the parent Variable product, even though we always manage stock at the parent product level, never at the variant level.

I've found code online that enumerates through the variants to see if any have inventory, but that option is not relevant here, since we don't manage inventory at that level.

So it seems that is_in_stock doesn't work as I'd expect for Variable products that manage inventory at the parent level, but I've not yet found anything relevant when stock is managed at the parent level. Maybe my Google-Fu is failing me.

What do I need to do to make this work?

Thanks!